# Batch to search file name on workstation and to create a txt or docx output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to create a batch file to search one of my workstations for a specific file by name. If the file is found I want to output the report into a txt or docx.

Below is what I have so far but it is only searching the root directory:

```
@echo off
C:
if exist C:\test.* (echo FILE_EXIST) else (echo FILE DOES NOT EXIST)
pause
```

Can someone please provide me with a sample of the batch that I need to make this work? Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to approach this problem. One of the simplest is to use `FOR /R /D` to iterate all the directory tree, and for each directory found, repeat your `IF EXIST` test. Read `HELP FOR`, try `FOR /R /D %a in (*) DO @IF EXIST %a\test.txt @echo %a` and then adjust it to your needs. Come back if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple i suppose using `dir`

```
@echo off
C:
dir /s/b test.*
pause
```

It will show *file not found* if there is no file with the name and will show the complete path of the file where the file(s) with that name is/are.

If you want the reports to be stored in a file use `dir /s/b test.* >reports.txt` instead.
The reports then will be stored in the file "reports.txt" in the very directory.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Is there a way to email the report to an email address?

Comment: Yes there is a way to send this as an email. Use sendemail tool. Mark my answer correct if it worked perfectly for others to follow.